# How can I make dired display .tbz2 files

Tags: dired, compression

When using dired and I see a .tar.xz file I can visit this file in other window (<mouse-1>) and the file is a browsable tar archive.

How do I get .tbz2 files to behave in the same way?

I am using emacs versions 25 and 27

Comment: look at varaiables `dired-compress-file-suffixes` and `dired-compress-files-alist` in file `dired-aux.el` then define your own custom suffix `\\.tbz2\\'`

Comment: Emacs 26 (and 28.0.50, so I presume 27 as well) recognized `.tbz2` as a suffix for a  bz2-compressed tar archive and does the right thing. That's with `-Q` so it should the case generally. Not sure about 25.

Comment: @NickD - dired-compress-file-suffixes does not have .tbz2 in so how does it work?